# Тяжелая задача с прямоугольниками

Tags: java

Два прямоугольника, расположенные в первом квадранте, со сторонами, параллельными осям координат, заданы координатами своих левого верхнего и правого нижнего углов. Для первого прямоугольника это точки с координатами (х1, у1) и (x2, 0), для второго — (х3, y3), (x4, 0).

***Определить, пересекаются ли данные прямоугольники, и вычислить площадь их общей части, если они пересекаются.***

Понял только то, что у меня есть точки x1, x2,x3,x4,y1, y3 а вот как решить задачу не пойму, помогите пж.

Comment: Вы уже нарисовали эту задачу на бумаге?

Comment: Да, пытался, но так и не понял что сделать надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и быть, вот Вам решение. Два прямоугольника перeсекаются, если расстояние (по оси Х) между их центрами меньше (или равно?) половины суммы их размеров (по оси Х).

Comment: Спасибо, вот после этого, я решил задачу

Answer (score 0):

Если заданы координаты левых и правых точек, значит `x1 < x2`, `x3 < x4`.

Прямоугольники *НЕ БУДУТ* пересекаться, если правая вершина одного находится левее левой вершины другого: `x2 < x3` или `x4 < x1`.

Иначе координаты пересечения будут такие:

- левая вершина:  `xL = Math.max(x1, x3), yL = Math.min(y1, y3)`
- правая вершина: `xR = Math.min(x2, x4), yR = 0`

Вычисление площади пересечения тривиально.

Comment: @Эникейщик Оба прямоугольника лежат нижней стороной на оси Х.

Comment: @Igor а, ну тада да

Comment: @AlexRudenko про 0 я не обратил внимания и комментарий уже удалил